# Get un-prefixed/un-escaped text with RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input text:

```
A B C D E \F G H I JKL \M
```

and I would like to mach all characters without a \ as prexix, each of the characters individually.
So basically, as a match, I'd like to get A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J, K and L, with F and M not passing because they are prefixed/escaped.

I got as far as

```
([^\\]([A-Z]{1}))
```

which works but not exactly as expected:
- `A` is ignored, because there is nothing before (and I am testing for anything but the backslash)
- each letter is matched with the space before
- `JKL` is matches as `J` with a space before, and `KL` as one string.

I have tried different other variations with parantheses but was not successful with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negated character class `[^\\]` is a *consuming* pattern that matches the text, adds it to the match value and advances the regex index to the end of the match.

Use a non-consuming [**negative lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\\)[A-Z]
^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%5BA-Z%5D&i=A%20B%20C%20D%20E%20%5CF%20G%20H%20I%20JKL%20%5CM). Being a non-consuming pattern, the `(?<!\\)` only checks if there is a backslash before an ASCII uppercase letter, and if there is any, the engine fails the match. If there is a `\`, the letter is matched (while the backslash remains missing in the match value).

C# code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\\)[A-Z]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```